# Kivy Label Unable to refresh when validating the Ip address

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building a Kivy interface with raspberry pi module.In the user interface I have status screen which shows the Ip address.If I disconnect the Ethernet cable,screen suppose to give me error label(**kivy screenone label:IpAddress**) and when I reconnect the Ethernet cable, label should be update back to Ip address. Unfortunately when I disconnect the Ethernet cable app shows the "Error" but when I Reconnect the Ethernet it not showing back my Ip Address. *Ipaddress* label stays as "Error"..

```
##this is the root widget
class Menu(BoxLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self._key_handler)
        #btn1 = ActionButton(text='',icon='./assest/usb.jpg')

    def _key_handler(self, instance, key, *args):
        if key is 27:
            self.set_previous_screen()
            return True

    def set_previous_screen(self):
        if self.manager.current != 'home':
            #self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            self.manager.transition = SwapTransition()


class ScreenOne(Screen,BoxLayout):

    stringIP=subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]
    print_ip = StringProperty(str(stringIP).strip("b'"))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenEnergy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_ip, 1)
        scheduler1 = BackgroundScheduler()
        scheduler1.add_job(self.update_ip, 'interval', seconds=1)
        scheduler1.start()
        # #self.update_ip()
        print("status window")


    def update_ip(self,*args):     
        try:
            # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
            # reachable
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            self.print_ip
            print("ip")
            #print("connected")
            return True
        except OSError:
            self.ids.ipAddress.text="[b][color=ff0000]Error[/color][/b]"
            print("not Ip ")
        return False

        # try:
        #     #socket.inet_aton(self.print_ip)
        #     #socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, self.print_ip)
        #     self.print_ip='\b(([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}'
        #     self.ids.ipLabel.text="faffxga"
        #         # legal
        # except socket.error:
        #     self.ids.ipLabel.text="adadadsadsa"
        # return False

        #         # Not legal

       class MenuApp(FlatApp):


    def build(self):
        my_callback=Menu()
        #ip_call =ScreenEnergy()
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(my_callback.is_connected, 'interval', seconds=1)
        #scheduler.add_job(ip_call.update_ip, 'interval', seconds=1)
        scheduler.start()
        return my_callback



if __name__ == '__main__':

    MenuApp().run()
```

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Menu>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    manager: screen_manager
    orientation: "vertical"
    ActionBar:

        size_hint_y: 0.15
        background_image: ''
        background_color: 0.349, 0.584, 0.917, 1
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:

            ActionButton:
                id:motorBtn
                text:''
                icon:'./assest/Ethernet.jpg'

    Manager:
        id: screen_manager

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        WrappedLabel:
            id:welcomeStatus
            text: "[b]Status[/b]"
            font_size:min(root.width,root.height)/15
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            row: 3
            padding:root.width*.02,root.height*.03
            spacing:min(root.width,root.height)*.02
            Label:   
                id:ipLabel
                size_hint_x: .15
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: '[b]IP Address :[/b]'
                markup:True 
            Label:
                id:ipAddress
                size_hint_x: .15
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: root.print_ip
                color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                bold:True
                markup:True  

<Screen 2>:

<Manager>:

    id: screen_manager
```

**UPDATE TWO:**
After  required modification to the code no more errors on terminal .. at least it's good sign!

```html
class ScreenOne(Screen,BoxLayout):
    print_ip = StringProperty('')
       
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenEnergy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_ip, 1)
        print("status window")
        
    
    def update_ip(self,*args):     
        try:
            # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
            # reachable
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            stringIP = subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]
            self.print_ip = str(stringIP).strip("b'")
            print("ip={self.print_ip}")
            return True
        except OSError:
            self.ids.ipAddress.text="[b][color=ff0000]Error[/color][/b]"
            print("not Ip ")
        return False
```

before disconnecting the Ethernet cable(looks Good)
[image]

after disconnecting the cable(looks good)
[image]

after reconnecting the Ethernet cable(not good)
[image]

looks like code stuck in  *except OSError:* because it's not changing back to Ethernet address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Not resetting of attribute, `print_ip` inside the `try` block after `socket.create_connection()` call.

## Solution

At `class ScreenOne`, do the following:

- Move `stringIP=subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]` to after `socket.create_connection()` call
- Replace class attribute, `print_ip = StringProperty(str(stringIP).strip("b'"))` with `print_ip = StringProperty('')`
- Add `self.print_ip = str(stringIP).strip("b'")` after `stringIP = subprocess.check()` call
- Replace `self.ids.ipAddress.text` with `self.print_ip`

## Snippets

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):

    print_ip = StringProperty('')
    ...

    def update_ip(self,*args):     
        try:
            # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
            # reachable
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            stringIP = subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]
            self.print_ip = str(stringIP).strip("b'")
            print(f"ip={self.print_ip}")
        except OSError:
            self.print_ip = "[b][color=ff0000]Error[/color][/b]"
            print("not Ip ")
```

Comment: Add `stringIP = subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]` between `socket.create_connection(...)` and `self.print_ip = str(...)`. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: Hi ikolim,Please kindly check the Update two that i add to question field if you can!! cheers!!

Comment: Replace `self.ids.ipAddress.text = ...` with `self.print_ip = ...` in `except OSError:` block. Also remove `return True` and `return False`.

Comment: It Works ikolim!!!! it works!! Thank you!!! I didn't change *except OSError: self.print_ip * as you said!!

Answer (score 1):

In the kivy file you're setting `id:ipAddress` which means the label will be looking at the `ipAddress` property of the `ScreenOne` object.

Because of the way Kivy properties work, any changes to that property will be automatically reflected in the label. So in the python code you should not be setting the label text directly; instead use `self.ipAddress.set("The New Value")`

You are also not resetting the label value after the error, so even after a connection is established in the try statement, the label will remain at the error value.

I recommend changing the update_ip function to this:

```py
def update_ip(self,*args):     
    try:
        # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
        # reachable
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        self.print_ip.set(str(stringIP).strip("b'"))
        print("ip")
        #print("connected")
        return True
    except OSError:
        self.print_ip.set("[b][color=ff0000]Error[/color][/b]")
        print("not Ip ")
    return False
```